# How to make GridLayout to respect columns setting?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

I had been trying to make gridlayout to give the same columns as i had specified in the code instead  i got  3 times  amount of my specification, any idea on why it is like this and how to solve this problem will be appreciated.

I have an ArrayList of type string with size of 150 string object an each of string is a text on JButton and then the JButton added to a JPanel with gridLayout Manager i wanted to create 15 rows and 10 colomns.

Here is the code

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
Gridlayout gridlayout = new GridLayout();
gridlayout.setRows(15);
gridlayout.setColumns(10);
gridlayout.setHgap(2);
gridlayout.setVgap(6);
panel.setLayout(gridlayout);
// now arraylist of type string, each string on Jbutton
for(ArrayList string: strings){
    panel.add(new JButton (string));
}
```

Comment: Set the row count to 0, giving the column count greater consideration when the container is laid out

Comment: @MadProgrammer when i set the row count to 0 and colomn remain the same it gave me the following error message :" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: rows and cols cannot both be zero"

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Comment: BTW - even if it was not a code snippet, that code is uncompilable due to things like `gridlayout.setcolomn(10);`.  Please stop wasting everybodys time with code 'something like' that being used.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, this code is compilable with the gridlayout.setRows(15) and gridlayout.setColomns(10)

Comment: Make sure you set the number of rows first

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for contribution, i got 10 colomns now just like i had wish, but the rows are 3 more times than i had wanted, i wanted to have 15 rows 10 colomns.

Comment: Column does not have 2 O's, so that dross seen above still would not compile.  Never ceases to amaze me when someone attempting programming has not yet mastered 'copy/paste'.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson, it never stop to amaze me when master of know it all never give the right solution lol

Comment: You wanna know why you haven't gotten an answer yet? It's because we **can't** reproduce your problem with that little code you've provided. Do like AndrewThompson said and Post an MCVE. Or like AndrewThompson is hinting at with his comment (I think), copy/paste your code, if you're too lazy to create an MCVE (key word minimal). But don't be surprised if you post 5000 lines of code and no one responds. Up to you if you want an answer or not.

Comment: i had like to thank all of you who had commented on this code,i had solve the issue, this is a school project and i felt it not to show all the code, even if i had like to it will be enormous,so i took to MCVE,run the code and it work just i had wish, then i went back to project, i created 3 Jpanel, one as the container for the rest two, give the first JPanel a borderlayout and the rest two the gridlayout manager, sort the giving data into two groups and added each group to the two remaining panel, then i got it done just like i wanted. thanks to MadProgrammer , Andrew thompson and peeskillet

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe there were not exactly 150 strings in your array.
The `GridLayout` manager does not complain if we put more
buttons into the grid. It simply creates a new column or row.

In the following example I create a grid with 2 columns and 2 rows 
but manage to add eight buttons there, without any error messages.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class GridLayoutDemo extends JFrame {

    public GridLayoutDemo() {

        initUI();

        setTitle("Grid of buttons");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));

        pnl.add(new JButton("Button"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("Button"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("Button"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("Button"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("Button"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("Button"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("Button"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("Button"));

        add(pnl);

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GridLayoutDemo ex = new GridLayoutDemo();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

That said, one should avoid using `GridLayout`. And other simple layout managers as well. 
In practice it is quite rare to find a situation where a `GridLayout` might be useful. Better learn & use some more powerful layout manager like `MigLayout` or `GroupLayout`.

[image: Grid of buttons]